# How to conditionally calculate the running total involving the sum of multiple columns?

Tags: sqlite

I have the following table:

| Date | Action | Quantity | Quantity_balance | Price | Commission | running_total_acb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-02 | buy | 150 | 150 | 110.21 | 5.95 |  |
| 2021-01-21 | buy | 360 | 510 | 106.87 | 5.95 |  |
| 2021-03-21 | sell | -360 | 150 | 106.87 | 5.95 |  |

...

The above table can be generated by:

```
CREATE TABLE transaction_record (
    row_id Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Date String NOT NULL,
    Action String NOT NULL,
    Quantity Integer NOT NULL,
    Price Float NOT NULL,
    Commission Float
);

INSERT INTO transaction_record (Date, Action, Quantity, Price, Commission)
    VALUES ("2021-01-02", "buy", 150, 110.21, 5.95),
            ("2021-01-21", "buy", 360, 106.87, 5.95),
            ("2021-03-21", "sell", -360, 106.87, 5.95);
```

Now for the `running_total_acb` column, there are three different cases:

case 1: if the value for the column `Action` in the same row is "buy", then it is calculated as `Price * Quantity + Commission + running_total_acb(from the previous row)`;

case 2: if the value for the column `Action` in the same row is "sell", then it is calculated as `running_total_acb(from the previous row) - (running_total_acb(from the previous row) / Quantity_balance) * Quantity`;

case 3: for the first row only, as there is no previous row, the `running_total_acb(from the previous row)` should be 0, instead of `Null`.

Note: In all three cases above, the `running_total_acb(from the previous row)` value is pseudo code, supposed to be referring to the value from the same column of the immediate previous row.

In order to generate and fill the values in the `running_total_acb` column, I have the following query:

```
WITH t_timepoint_ordered AS (
            SELECT  RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Date, row_id) AS transact_step,
                    Date,
                    Action,
                    Quantity,
                    Price,
                    Commission
            FROM transaction_record
            ORDER BY transact_step
        ),
            
t_with_quantity_balance AS (
            SELECT *,
                   SUM(Quantity) OVER (ORDER BY transact_step ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Quantity_balance
            FROM t_timepoint_ordered
        )

SELECT *, CASE
            WHEN outer_t.Action = "buy"
              THEN (SELECT inner_t.total_ACB_balance + (inner_t.Price * inner_t.Quantity + inner_t.Commission) FROM t_with_quantity_balance AS inner_t WHERE inner_t.transact_step = outer_t.transact_step - 1)
            WHEN outer_t.Action = "sell"
              THEN (SELECT inner_t.total_ACB_balance + (inner_t.total_ACB_balance / inner_t.Quantity_balance * inner_t.Quantity) FROM t_with_quantity_balance AS inner_t WHERE inner_t.transact_step = outer_t.transact_step - 1)
            ELSE 0
          END AS total_ACB_balance
        FROM t_with_quantity_balance AS outer_t;
```

This query doesn't work. Running it gives `Error: no such column:outer_t.total_ACB_balance`

I was expecting the values for the three rows for the `running_total_acb` to be:

| running_total_acb |
| --- |
| 16537.45 |
| 55016.60 |
| 16181.35 |

I suppose this error is from the fact that by the time that the inner_t referring to that column of the outer_t, that column hasn't been established yet??

How to make this work in SQLite?

Comment: What is your expected output for this sample data?

Comment: @forpas I expected that the `running_total_acb` column to be correctly filled, following the three different cases that I discussed in my post.

Comment: We're looking for the actual numbers. Data as a CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements would be useful too for easy creation of a test database.

Comment: @Shawn I've just edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```sql
WITH first_row AS (SELECT Date, Action, Quantity, Price, Commission
                   FROM transaction_record ORDER BY Date LIMIT 1),
     cte AS (SELECT Date, Action, Quantity, Quantity AS Quantity_balance, Price, Commission,
                    CASE Action
                      WHEN 'buy' THEN Price * Quantity + Commission
                      WHEN 'sell' THEN 0.0
                    END AS running_total_acb
               FROM first_row
             UNION ALL
              SELECT tr.Date, tr.Action, tr.Quantity, cte.Quantity_balance + tr.Quantity,
                     tr.Price, tr.Commission,
                     CASE tr.Action
                       WHEN 'buy' THEN
                         tr.Price * tr.Quantity + tr.Commission + cte.running_total_acb
                       WHEN 'sell' THEN
                         cte.running_total_acb - abs(cte.running_total_acb / cte.Quantity_balance * tr.Quantity)
                     END
              FROM transaction_record AS tr
              JOIN cte ON tr.Date = (SELECT tr2.Date FROM transaction_record AS tr2 WHERE tr2.Date > cte.Date ORDER BY tr2.Date LIMIT 1))
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY Date;
```

produces, using your sample data,

```
Date        Action  Quantity  Quantity_balance  Price   Commission  running_total_acb
----------  ------  --------  ----------------  ------  ----------  -----------------
2021-01-02  buy     150       150               110.21  5.95        16537.45
2021-01-21  buy     360       510               106.87  5.95        55016.6
2021-03-21  sell    -360      150               106.87  5.95        16181.3529411765
```

(You'll want an index on `transaction_record.Date` if you don't already have one.)

Comment: If Sqlite let you use computed values in window functions (`SELECT lag(running_total_acb) .... AS running_total_acb ....`) it'd be a lot simpler.

Comment: Just to expand knowldge base, do you think window functions and correlated subqueries will also work in this case?